# Sum a column except current cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is it possible to sum all values in a column *EXCEPT* the value in the current cell? That is, the cell that is to hold the result.

With a normal `SUM(E:E)` command the result is `#REF!` with a *Circular dependency detected* error.

[image: Example]

Can I in some way leave out the current cell from such a sum command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a normal formula it is not possible. A custom function doesn't works as well (pure JavaScript). Therefore I wrote this little script to act as a work-around.

### Code

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Complete Range", functionName: "sumColumn"}];
  ss.addMenu("Sum", menu);
}  

function sumColumn() {
  var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  var fontColors = activeRange.getFontColors();
  var data = activeRange.getValues(), sum = 0, indexText = 0;
  for(var i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(typeof data[i][0] == "number") {
      fontColors[i][0] = "general-black";
      sum += data[i][0];
    } else {
      if(data[i][0] == "#REF!") {
        fontColors[i][0] = "red";
        indexText = i;      
      }      
    }
  }
  data[indexText][0] = sum;
  activeRange.setFontColors(fontColors).setValues(data);
}
```

### Explained

The script will create a new menu entry called `Sum` when the file opens. Add either the `SUM` function (with complete column range to force a circular dependency) or the word `#REF!` into the cell you want the total sum to appear in and select a column range or the range that needs to be summed up:

[image]

Select from the menu the (only) option `Complete Range`. From this part on, the script is quite straightforward. It will sum the numbers and will store the index when it hits the `#REF!`. The rest will be ignored. After that, the text entry will be replaced by the total sum and the lot (data) is added to the active range.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Sum with Circular Dependency](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGpTMDJ5M21DOUFqX2dfTEpEZ3FZa3c&usp=sharing)**

### Remarks

In order to determine the sum, I've colored the total sum in red. If you want to do it all over again, just type somewhere (once) the word `#REF!`.

Add the script by selecting Tools>Script editor. Save/initiate the script by pressing the "bug" button. This will trigger the authentication process of the script, because it needs to gain access to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Impressive work, and thanks a lot. But what a solution for a simple wish.

Answer (score 7):

I know this page is quite old and likely no longer relevant to OP, but I came across this page via Google when trying to find a solution to the same problem. I found an alternate path so I figured I'd chime in with a simpler, formula-based solution in case someone else finds this page in the future. We can use the =Indirect() formula to influence our =sum() and get everything outside of the current row without circular reference errors. Using OPs original example of column E:

```
=(sum(indirect("E1:E"&row()-1))+sum(indirect("E"&row()+1&":E999999")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@RickyFish89's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138373):

You can use the relative address as well, like this

```
=sum(indirect(ADDRESS(1, column())&":"&ADDRESS(row()-1, column())))+N("Sums all values in the column of the cell of this formula that come before the cell")
```

(of course the `+N(...)` is optional and just serves as a comment)
and then of course you can substitute the rest of the formula given by @RickyFish89 in the same way.
As I tend only to need the first part the rest is usually not needed for me.